# Failed To Write Session Data error in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I receive this error when I try to activate the Bad Behavior plugin in WordPress:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: open(D:\Temp\php\session\\sess_pvu0f81uuqt7l8b8b2l2e380p3, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (D:\Temp\php\session\) in Unknown on line 0
```

I realized I didn't have a 'Temp' folder so I created one along with the correct subfolders and placed it in the root directory of my site. Even after logging out and logging back into WordPress and clearing my cookies, I still get the same error. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

I'm on a Godaddy Windows shared hosting plan. I'm using the latest version of WordPress (4.7.4) and all of my plugins are up to date.

Comment: I think this might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369298/godaddy-php-and-shared-windows-server-file-uploading-issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after being on the phone with GoDaddy support for almost an hour. To solve the error I had to change the session.save_path in the php.ini file in my site's root directory like this:

```
session.save_path="D:/path to webroot directory/Temp/php/session"
```

Since my site is on a Windows hosting plan I had to rename the php.ini to .user.ini to get the server to recognize it.